# Electric field produced by a charged ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields

I have a question I couldn't find an answer for anywhere. There is a ring of radius $R$ which is charged uniformly with linear density $\lambda$, and I have to find the electric field on any point of the axis of the ring. So far so good, but this $\lambda$ includes both free and polarization charges, and the ring is in a region which is dielectric, with $\varepsilon_r$. I don't know if I can find the electric field just like $\lambda$ didn't include polarization charges. What do you say?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider the $\vec{D}$ field ...

Comment: Probably, but how do I separate the free charges from the polarization charges?

Comment: Let's make sure we understand each other.  Can you tell me where the polarization charges are, and what medium they "belong" to?  And by "free", I assume you mean "not bound to the medium", and fixed in position (uniformly in a ring) so that they can't move.

Comment: that linear density $\lambda$ is for the ring, and it includes both free charges (which somehow got there) and polarization charges OF THE RING. Nothing is said about the other dielectric, nor do I know the permitivity of the ring (since I'm told about polarization charges, I assume it's a dielectric too). So yes, 'free' is what you mean.
Anyway, in a couple of hours I have an exam and the answer you think is closest to 'the answer' will be appreciated. The question was  because I don't know if when calculating E without Gauss's law I can use this $\lambda$ which has also polarization charges.

Comment: I have to apologize:  I don't quite understand the question. Perhaps I'm not reading it carefully enough.  Are you saying that there is a one-dimensional ring of charge of linear density $\lambda$ which is embedded in a torus-shaped dielectric, which in turn is embedded in another space-filling dielectric? Or a torus-shaped uniform charge distribution co-located with a dielectric? Perhaps the original wording might help me.  Someone else may see this better than I.  But probably too late to help.   :(

Comment: Don't worry, luckily I didn't have anything like that on my exam. Let's see if you get the idea: there is a ring of charge with density $\lambda$, a ring like... a ring. This ring instead of being in vacuum is inside a dielectric $\varepsilon_r$ which surrounds it (this dielectric is 'infinite')

Comment: We're not supposed to have back-and-forth discussions on Physics SE, but I'll risk it :) because I'm still unclear.  All we know about the ring is that it is a ring of charge.  There's no mechanism for it to have a polarization or polarization charge.  The medium it's in can, of course.

Comment: As @garyp mentioned, you should work with $\mathbf{D}$. Since you know how to solve for $\mathbf{E}$ the ring with linear density $\lambda$ in free space. Call that solution $\mathbf{E}_{old}$, then one can show that $\mathbf{D}=\epsilon_0 \mathbf{E}_{old}$ for the ring in the dielectric. The rest is then straightforward.